# Stop location updates with FusedLocation

Tags: android

How do I stop the FusedLocation listener for updates?
This is how I set it up:

```
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                // Update UI with location data


                // Write a message to the database

        };
    };
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //
    } else {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);

    }
```

How to stop listening for location updates in the `onStop` method for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation recommends stop locations in onPause method and restart updates in onResume method.

The code will be something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
            mLocationCallback,
            null /* Looper */);
}
```

Check this link for more info: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates

Comment: If I'm on a fragment, should I put this code in the parent activity, or in the fragment's onResume and onPause?

Comment: Depends of the implementation but to be sure use the fragment methods. Here is more info about that: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle.